# maintain value of variable outside function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I try to manipulate a variable inside a function. But it seems to forget the values once I exit the function, eventhough the variable is declared outside the function.

The essential code:

```
var posts = {};                

            // Perform a data request
            // skjutsgruppens-page
            $.oajax({
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/197214710347172/feed?limit=500",
                    *SNIP*
                    success: function(data) {
                    $.extend(posts, data);
                }
            });


            // Gruppen
            $.oajax({
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/2388163605/feed?limit=500",
                *snip*
                success: function(data) {
                    $.extend(posts, data);
                }
            });
```

The oajax retrievies data from facebook. I want to make a variable that contains the data from both oajax methods.

The actual code: [http://eco.nolgren.se/demo/resihop/#](http://eco.nolgren.se/demo/resihop/)

Comment: This just got a lot stranger... It seems asthough the extend-method only applies when I reload the page. Wtf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely that the `success` function executes at an arbitrary time in the future--unless you specifically access `posts` after you *know* the `success` function has executed, you will receive undefined results, completely dependent on function and access timing.

The best approach is to handle this correctly by doing necessary work inside in the success function, or use something like jQuery's [`.when` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Comment: You are correct, success executes when I get an answer. that's when I want to extend posts with data. Is that not what  I'm doing?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren You tell us--in the success function, after you call `extend`, is the data in the object? Is the data in a format suitable for use by `.extend`? At what point are you accessing `posts` and the data is *not* there?

Comment: it seems to be there as though the data in posts is the data from the last loading of the page, and it alternates between the two objects. I really don't understand this...

Comment: @KristofferNolgren Alternates between what two objects? When do you make the Ajax calls? When do you access the data in `posts` outside of the Ajax calls? You need to update your question with more details, IMO.

Comment: I looked at a bit more. It turnded out, the problem wasn't when the extend was used, the problem was that extend overwrote the first data with the second data. The solution was passing true as the first variable.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren Ah, gotcha--glad you worked it out. You might consider creating your own answer and accepting it, since mine was way off-base, or editing mine with the additional information.